# Get all table data in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access into a Database data through a Django view. The problem is that when I query it, it just returns me the result of the **unicode** function on the model. How can I access to the other fields of the model?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you're asking. Could you give us an example of the line of code where you are querying the model?

Comment: I read the table like this: `Table.objects.all()`

Comment: can you show the query you have ? (the view code and the models code).

Comment: And what did the results look like?

Comment: If you print the table, it's meant to return just the unicode function, but if you try to address other items in the list, I bet you can without issue.

Comment: In the django prompt, I execute the query above and I get that: `[<Table: John>, <Table: Paul>]` Then I do a for loop over all the fields and the error comes when I do something like `i['surname']`

Comment: This is a basic question that's covered well by the tutorial.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

say you have a student database,

```
student_list = Student.objects.all()
for student in student_list:
    print student.name
```

The other fields can be used in the iterator, using the dot(`.`) operator